# Avoid replica of code inside function (Javascript only)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to get the value from text box field on button click which invokes function that performs operation and store result in another text field. I have six operations - addition, subtraction, multiply, division, maximum, minimum and hence six functions. I have to use the code that get the value from text fields many times in order to perform operations. I want to use the code one time and get the values handed over to me in function to get different results. Below code will make it clear-

```
function sum()
{
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b= parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var res =document.getElementById("res");
    res.value =a+b;
}
function substract()
{
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b= parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var res =document.getElementById("res");
    res.value =a-b;
}
function multiply()
{
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b= parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var res =document.getElementById("res");
    res.value =a*b;
}
```

and so on...for division, maximum, minimum and average.
   (here) the first three lines of code in each function are same. 
What way this can be done? ( will array or return method work?)

Comment: you could use global variables, or pass a,b,res inside a object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a destructuring function:

```
function values() {
    return [parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value), parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value), document.getElementById("res")];
}
```

Then in your other functions:

```
function sum() {
    var [a, b, res] = values();
    res.value = a + b;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem @harpreet. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark to the left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use a new method that returns an object containing a and b.

```
var res = document.getElementById('res');
function getWidthAndHeight() {
  return {
    w: parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value),
    h: parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value)
  };
}
```

So, your first method could be:

```
function sum() {
    var sizes = getWidthAndHeight();
    res.value = sizes.w + sizes.h;
}
```

As Pixelmo has in the other answer, setting the `res` variable in a different scope would also be beneficial. Updated answer above...

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more complicated but less repetitious solution is to have a base version of the function that contains the repeated code, and pass in a function that you want to apply to the numbers:

```
function computeWith(op) {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

    var res = document.getElementById("res");
    res.value = op(a, b);
}
```

Then pass in the operator using a lambda, or an existing function:

```
function multiply() {
    computeWith((a, b) => a * b);
}

function add() {
    computeWith((a, b) => a + b);
}

function average() {
    computeWith((a, b) => (a + b) / 2);
}
```

Those functions are so small now though, they arguably don't need to exist unless you like having names attached to the code, or they're being used in multiple places.

Comment: Oh yes!! Thanks. What to do for minimum and maximum operation?

Comment: @harpreet `(a, b) => Math.max(a, b)`, or your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a operation type as parameter, and do the operation for the type in a function.

```js
function op(type)
{
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var res = document.getElementById("res");
  
  switch (type) {
  case 'sum':
    res.value = a + b;
    break;
  // so on...
  }
}

op('sum')
```

```html
<input id="num1" value="1">
<input id="num2" value="2">
<input id="res">
```